# Moving element from container does not empty container?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct number {
    int n{666};
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<number> vec;
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;
    number n;
    vec.push_back(n);
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;
    auto b = std::move(vec.front());
    std::cerr << "b: " << b.n << std::endl;
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
0
1
b: 666
1
```

Shouldn't the last `1` be `0`?

Comment: vec.front() should be the n which is an instance of number?

Comment: Turn that into a reply?

Comment: @0x5453: Ubs, you are right. So my first comment I already had deleted was : Move an number did not move the content from a vector... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have used the value at the front and you want to get rid of it you will need to `erase` it from the vector. I won't talk about the `front()` returning a ref as 0x5453 mentioned that. But there is no reason to use `std::move` there - all that does is cast the value to a rvalue reference it does not actually "move" anything on its own.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct number {
    int n{666};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<number> vec;
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;
    number n;
    vec.push_back(n);
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;

    // Since this is a ref, and your struct is simple - just copy
    auto b {vec.front()};
    // Now remove the element
    vec.erase(vec.begin());

    std::cerr << "b: " << b.n << std::endl;
    std::cerr << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::move` doesn't even know that the thing it moved was in a container. The block of memory that the vector owns is still there, just in an unspecified state. It's up to you to manage the vector.